# Augmented Reality Breadboard Markerless Method with Vuforia and Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am trying to develop an Augmented Reality Mobile Application using Vuforia and Unity3D

In the application, the phone will capture an empty breadboard with a live camera. Whenever the camera detects the breadboard, the electronic components will appear on the breadboard. The electronic components should be in proper places on the breadboard, where it is places correctly in the hole of a breadboard.

Reference video: [AR Breadboard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Su7oa4O2mW8)

We will be using both marker and markerless method. We've done research from academic papers as this is for our thesis and was used for Review of Related Literatures. But, we still don't know the exact approach or method on how will it be done since all the academic papers we've gathered are straightforward and direct to the results.

We knew that we need to code the scripts for us to interact the components just like on a simulation (e.g. Tinkercad, Wokwi). But my problem is just what are the exact steps in using Marker and Markerless method. Like, what should I do in order to trace the breadboard and its holes to properly put the components in the breadboard.

I hope someone here can help me answer here, Thanks!

I tried watching tutorials, and blogs from YouTube and Unity about Augmented Reality. They all helped in giving me fundamental knowledge. But I still have limited knowledge, the videos from YouTube do not really give tutorials. It just shows that it exist.

Comment: Using Vuforia and marker-based or marker-less tracking might be insufficient in accuracy for your use case. Still, you could at least try it out. In the video they seem to be using some kind of marker tracking as well which seems to be sufficient. In Vuforia, you would use an image target for example. If you have a 3d model of your breadboard, you could also try model tracking but that is usually intended for larger objects

Comment: I will take note of that 3D model of a breadboard you said and is on progress in blender. Might I ask some suggestion for a better accuracy if marker-based or marker-less tracking is insufficient?

Comment: I guess one option would be to apply ML-based object tracking. Since you aim to detect a very specific, pre-defined object (breadboard), this seems to be a perfect use case. Normally you would offload the inference to an external server. However, depending on the computing power of your phone you might be able to do this even locally. Unity also offers basic frameworks to achieve such things. Maybe look into this

Comment: Thanks for this info. I'll be back on this comment to give update, and post solutions for future reference also since tutorials about this are few.